# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects while getting a JSON object

Tags: python

Python cannot get a simple JSON object via HTTP due to cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects while getting a JSON object error. However, the same script works without any issues on a different machine with the same setup (OS, python version, python modules, etc.)

Version used: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
OS: RHEL 6.6

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json


def main():
   f = requests.get("http://peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health")
   health = f.json()
   print health

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
./gettest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gettest.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "./gettest.py", line 7, in main
    f = requests.get("http://peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 279, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 374, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 219, in send
    r = self.build_response(request, resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 96, in build_response
    response.encoding = get_encoding_from_headers(response.headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 281, in get_encoding_from_headers
    content_type, params = cgi.parse_header(content_type)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/cgi.py", line 310, in parse_header
    parts = _parseparam(';' + line)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

Output of the same script on the second machine:

```
./gettest.py
{u'status': u'green', u'number_of_nodes': 7, u'unassigned_shards': 0, u'timed_out': False, u'active_primary_shards': 1441, u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch', u'relocating_shards': 0, u'active_shards': 2882, u'initializing_shards': 0, u'number_of_data_nodes': 4}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you in advance.

It reads from file OK, it just seems to be having a problem with the response it is getting from the URL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json

def main():
   f = open("/etc/zabbix/testjson").read()
   health = json.loads(f)
   print health

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
 # ./gettest2.py
{u'status': u'green', u'number_of_nodes': 7, u'unassigned_shards': 0, u'timed_out': False, u'active_primary_shards': 1441, u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch', u'relocating_shards': 0, u'active_shards': 2882, u'initializing_shards': 0, u'number_of_data_nodes': 4}
```

No problems with getting the response with CURL:

```
# curl http://peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":7,"number_of_data_nodes":4,"active_primary_shards":1441,"active_shards":2882,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0}
```

....

```
curl -s -D - -o /dev/null peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 230
```

utils.py debugging result:

```
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(277)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> content_type = headers.get('content-type')
(Pdb) n
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(278)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> print content_type
(Pdb) n
('content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(279)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> if not content_type:
(Pdb)
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(282)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> content_type, params = cgi.parse_header(content_type)
(Pdb)
TypeError: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects"
```

Output of debugging on a server where the script works shows that content_type is different:

```
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(277)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> content_type = headers.get('content-type')
(Pdb) n
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(278)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> print content_type
(Pdb) n
application/json; charset=UTF-8
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(279)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> if not content_type:
(Pdb) n
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py(282)get_encoding_from_headers()
-> content_type, params = cgi.parse_header(content_type)
(Pdb) n
```

Workaround (very bad one indeed but I don't use phyton for anything else so I can live with that):

added the following line to utils.py get_encoding_from_headers()

```
content_type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: On that second machine, are you running the same version of Python? If you save the JSON to a file, and try to parse it with the json module, does it work?

Comment: Yes, same version of python. It reads ok from file, see edited question.

Comment: "print f.status_code" u getting in other machine where its not working

Comment: Your server is sending *invalid headers*, violating HTTP standards. Can you show us the output of `curl -D - -o /dev/null http://peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health`.

Comment: the same output ending with "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects", no status code displayed.

Comment: Specifically, your `Content-Type` header contains an invalid parameter format, and parsing it fails.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, here you go. added to the question

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: can you re-run that with the `-s` flag added? That'll remove the timing information. `curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://peslog001.abc.local:9200/_cluster/health`. Sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not a problem, done.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: for some reason `requests.utils.get_encoding_from_headers()` is passing a tuple to `cgi.parse_header()`, and I don't see an obvious reason why yet. You do appear to have an older version of `requests` installed; the line numbers don't match my recent version. What version do you have?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have python-requests-1.1.0-4.el6.noarch on both of the servers.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: wow, that's almost prehistoric. The current releases are in the 2.x range, 1.1.0 dates from January 2013. Still, the [version of that piece of code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v1.1.0/requests/utils.py#L270) doesn't give any hints as to why `headers.get('content-type')` returned a tuple here.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: It is probably a bug in that older version of `requests` however. Try installing the latest `requests` version in a virtualenv and see if it works any better here.

Comment: The problem is, I have 5 other servers with the exact same setup with the exact same python packages and this works on all of them (just checked it), except for the problematic one :). So I can make this script work almost anywhere but not on that particular machine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue even with requests 1.1.0 on Python 2.6; I used [this little script on Python 3](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/30fb35a3638bfa0fa7a2) to serve the request, created a 2.6 virtualenv with `requests` 1.1.0 installed, then used `requests.get('http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health')` to try and reproduce the issue. I'll play some more, perhaps the server doesn't use the right line separators.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: is there any possibility that the local installation of `requests` was corrupted? Are you 100% certain that the `requests` module you import is the one from the RPM? Check `requests.__file__` to be certain.

Comment: yes, it is the one from the RPM (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc) and I have also reinstalled requests package.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: at this point in time I cannot reproduce your problem at all; I'd now start inserting `pdb.set_trace()` into the `requests` code and start tracing things in detail; but I cannot without actually being able to trigger the issue.

Comment: Are there any proxies configured? Run `python -c "from urllib import getproxies; print getproxies()"` to find out. An empty dictionary means *nope*.

Comment: No proxies. Let me know where I should insert pdb.set_trace(), I can try that.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: you'd start at `requests.utils.get_encoding_from_headers()` to see why `content_type` is being set to a `tuple`, and what is in that tuple. It'll take more spelunking to then trace back to where that tuple is coming from.

Comment: Another way would be to use strace and grep the `open` system calls

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have posted some trace results where I printed the content_type variable ('content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')

Comment: @IokanaanIokan: yes, I see that both the key and the value of the header are *both* returned. That's not normal behaviour, only the *value* should be returned. Your mission, should you accept it, is to figure out why that is. Is the `headers` object a different type? Where all values set to such tuples? Where where they set then? Etc. This is not something I can help with in comments, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure, you alredy helped a lot. Thanks!